# All pairs (as tuples) of integers adding to a given integer N

Tags: python

I want to store all pairs of integers whose sum is equal to N as tuples.
Here is my code so far:

```
m = []
l = []
degree = 9
for i in range(0, degree):
    m += [degree - i];
    l += [i]
    pairs = (m[i]),(l[i])    
pairs
```

This code return only last pair:

```
(1, 8)
```

What I want is this:

```
(9, 0),(8, 1),(7, 2),(6, 3),(5, 4),(4, 5),(3, 6),(2, 7),(1, 8)
```

Can you help me identify and fix the error in my code?

Comment: Your last statement, `pairs` only returns the _latest_ value of pairs. Instead of that, you could for example do `print([(m1,l1) for m1,l1 in zip(m,l)])`

Comment: You are rewriting `pairs` with each iteration. You need to initialize it ***before*** the loop, and `append` to it

Comment: The code shown here makes no sense at all, and has multiple issues. If you want to fix the code, that does not make an appropriate question here; we need questions about **one** issue which you have *already identified* - we don't do tutoring. If you are instead just asking about how to get the result, it would be better not to show code like this - but the question is still too broad: solving the problem involves following multiple logical steps.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: allow me to disagree; this code, though not optimal, almost does the intended job; the main (and let's say only) issue is the final statement, that doesn't yield the intended result.

Comment: Oh, I see the approach now. That's... strange, but it would otherwise work, yes. In that case, the question is still surely a duplicate; the basic technique here is covered by e.g. [How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a loop? Can I put them in a list?](/questions/44564414). This code is not in a function, so the setup is a bit different, but the conceptual problem and the solution are the same.

Comment: That said, feration48, shouldn't your code also return (0,9) ? @KarlKnechtel: indeed the code is 'strange' (which I would attribute to beginner's clumsiness; I've often written clumsy code by overthinking things, and still do from time to time :) ).

Comment: @Swifty Yes, it should return (0,9) too. I don't understand why that's not the last output...

Comment: "I don't understand why that's is not the last output." Please start by **reading the documentation** for `range`, in order to understand what numbers are `in range(0, degree)`, and thus what values `i` will have each time through the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way by defining a new pair's `list`, appending it inside the loop, and finally printing.

```
m = []
l = []
degree = 9
pairs = []
for i in range(0, degree):
    m += [degree - i];
    l += [i]
    pairs.append((m[i],l[i]))
print(pairs)
```

Comment: Does that mean that tuple pairs are always and in any case stored as list?

Comment: @feration48 yeap, if you want them as collective pairs then you need to append to the list or if you want to print then you can do without appending it

Comment: Why even use `m` and `l`? It can just be `pairs.append((degree-i, i))`

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes agreed with you sir, we can do that also. I just added as per OP's question